# Is there a possibility to read NFC tags from Android without intents?

Tags: android, tags, nfc

I'm a bit lost when using NFC with Android.

I want to do the following: 
- Use one NFC tag as token
- Read it in Android and show some functionallity 
- If phone is removed from token dipaly message
- If phone gets reconnected or connects to another token show another functionallity

I used an intent filter in the AndroidManifest file for `android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED` and an xml for filtering `android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED` .

The main activity opens succesfully , and if another tag is attached

```
 @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) { ...}
```

gets called.

I also use a Timer to check wether the tag is still conected (basically `ndefTag.connect()` ; `NdefMessage ndefMsg= ndefTag.getNdefMessage();` and then looking wether anything is recieved.

I set the launch mode of the Activity to `android:launchMode="singleInstance` as otherwise the app was completly restarted each time a new tag was put to phone.

Now i got completly lost with the intent system, as normally main was launching other activities, and with the intent is was jumping back to main with losses of the current activity and current screen information.

So my question is about two parts:
- is it really so complicated that intents need to be used? Cant i just connect somehow to the NFC reader of the phone and just poll the thing every few seconds? Ask wether an tag is connected and what data is on the tag. With the NDEF_DISCOVERED/TECH_Discovered combination i have seen that sometimes it just hangs. (also if it not a SingleInstance-Activity - also a new activity does sometimes not get started). (prefered)
- or is there some clean way to forward NFC-Intents to the actual activity of the app? Or to say at runtime that the main should not be called but some background task which handles the connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to read NFC cards without Intents and it is a much more reliable process especially if writing to cards

Use `enableReaderMode` instead https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter#enableReaderMode(android.app.Activity,%20android.nfc.NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)

Basically you get to a Set a callback function to get called when a Tag is discovered, the callback function is run in a separate thread instead of an Intent being passed to your main UI thread.

Whereas with `enableForegroundDispatch` you App gets paused while the system App reads the card and then resumes your App and passes it the New Intent. This pausing is probably why you were loosing you activity state.

With `enableReaderMode` Your App does not get paused while it reads the card.

Basic operations is:-

1) Implement Callback method

2) OnResume enableReaderMode and OnPause disableReaderMode

3) In onTagDsicovered (The callback function)
Connect once to tag, `getNdefMessage` in loop with a try block to handle the Exception generated when the tag leaves the reading range or Loop testing `isConnected` after reading the NDEF message once.

4) runOnUiThread the action you want based on the NDEF message

5) Do what you want done when the tag leaves reading ranged (or just let the reader callback thread exit, ready to read a new card.

Comment: Thank you. And yes you are right about the enableForegroundDispatch - it triggered onPause of Activities.

Comment: `enableReaderMode` also gives you control of the sound as well as running in a separate thread, which is critical if writing as it controls the user behaviour. If you want some concrete code examples, just ask, I can extract them from my NFC App